# How to express $num \cdot 1.06 ^{x - 1} + num \cdot 1.06 ^{x - 2} + \dots + num \cdot 1.06 ^{x - x}$ mathematically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to express 
$$
num \cdot 1.06 ^{x - 1} + num \cdot 1.06 ^{x - 2} + \dots + num \cdot 1.06 ^{x - x}
$$ mathematically?

I think it can be:
$$
x \cdot num \cdot (1.06 ^{x - 1} + 1.06 ^{x - 2} + \dots + 1.06 ^{x - x})
$$
but then I don't know how to keep transforming it.

Additionally, if it is 
$$
num \cdot 1.06 ^{x - 1} + num \cdot 1.06 ^{x - 2} + \dots + num \cdot 1.06 ^{x - y}
$$
what might the expression be?

Answer (score 1):

You could write
$$
num \cdot \sum_{i=1}^x 1.06^{x-i}
$$
which can be rewritten to
$$
num \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{x-1} 1.06^{i}
$$
Furthermore, have a look at [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) if you want to find an even simpler form of this.

Comment: Do you know how to write this expression to wolframalpha.com?

Comment: @AeroWang Write "n sum_(i=0)^(x - 1) 1.06^i". Here $n=num$